# ASP.NET - Failed to map the path '/myappname'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I'm getting this really annoying error when trying to set up a new application in IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I'm adding a new application under the default website in IIS 7.5, *myappname*

I have the application pool for the application set to *ASP.NET v4.0*

I've tried copying the files from another application that is working on the same server, different website, and it still fails, so I don't think it has anything to do with the web.config settings.

If I browse to *http://localhost/myappname* (or browse to any file/path under that application) I get the below error:

> ### Server Error in '/myappname' Application.
>
> Failed to map the path '/myappname'.  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the
>   path '/myappname'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/myappname'.]
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +336
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to map the path '/myappname'.]
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11700992
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4869221
> ```

I really don't get it. ALSO - if I go to the "Edit Application" dialog, and use the "Test Settings" button, then I get a error:

"There was an error while performing this operation. Details: Invalid application path"

which is BS, because I selected the path using the `...` button to browse for the path.

Also, that same error occurs when I use the "Test Settings" button on some of the other **working** websites on the server, so I'm not sure what to make of that and whether it's even relevant.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is not clear from the question. I can suggest the following solution. try your best

1.check whether your application pool is running in Integrated mode.
2.If you have a default route mapped then try right click the application in IIS => manage application =>browse 
3.Try Adding  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); in the Application_Start()  in global.asax